# add a class to particular row in codeigniter using table class

Tags: php, codeigniter

How can I add a class to particular row in codeigniter using table class?

Comment: *(poll)* No, it is impossible

Answer (score 1):

You can't add a class to a row in the same way you can added extra attributes to other elements CI-style. You can, however, add a class to every td IN A ROW, and then operate on the class as it references the entire row:

```
$td1 = array(
    'data'  => '/*actual html you want in the td*/',
    'class' => 'myclass'
);
$table->add_row($td1);
```

It's annoying to have to do every single td like that, and it isn't really what you want to have to do, but it's the best out there from all the solutions that I've seen.

Answer (score -2):

I would stay away from the CI table class if i were you; it is overly messy and doesnt really make things any easier or save you work.

I prefer this:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4">
<tr>
<th>Col One</th>
<th>Col Two</th>
<th>Col Three</th>
</tr>

<?php if($table_data != FALSE){?>   
<?php foreach($table_data->result() as $row){?>

<tr <?php echo (expr to find the row)? 'class="your_class"' : ''; ?>>

<td></td>
<td></td>

<td><a href="#"></a></td>

</tr>
<?php }?>
<?php }?>
</table>
```

Comment: Doesn't it, could you please explain?

Comment: To question was how to do something, not what your opinion on its implementation

Comment: Wow, ok, guy, so you will agree it has something to do with the question asked?

Comment: um... there about programming... there both using php... there both related to html tables...

Comment: An equally useless statement: "I don't like Codeigniter so here's how you can do this in CakePHP". It doesn't answer the question asked so Mbrevda is correct.