# How can I add attributes to <th> tag of table generated in codeigniter framework

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
<?php
//setting table headings
$this->table->set_heading('Report Id','Patient Name','Reg date', 'Test code', 'Actions');

//defining table template
$tmpl = array('table_open' => '<table data-toggle="table" data-show-refresh="true" data-show-toggle="true" data-show-columns="true" data-search="true"  data-pagination="true" data-sort-name="date" data-sort-order="desc" data-show-export="true">', 'heading_cell_start' => '<th data-sortable="true">',);

$this->table->set_template($tmpl);
//generating table
echo $this->table->generate($reports);
?>
```

This generates a table and I want to add some attributes to the tag, like

```
<th data-field="reportid" data-sortable="true">Report Id</th>
<th data-field="patientname" data-sortable="true">Patient Name</th>
<th data-field="date" data-sortable="true">Reg date</th>
```

How can I add these  ---- `data-field="reportid"` `data-sortable="true"`---  attributes?

Comment: you can simply use normal table

Comment: but i want to add data of table using array variable like above

Comment: is this table data coming from your database??

Comment: yes  n i don't want to use loops to display data, i am using codeignitor framework

Comment: loops means?? `foreach` ??

Comment: yes,   .... in codeignitor i can pass array and it can generate table automatically

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81501/discussion-between-mahethekiller-and-abdulla).

Comment: you just pass data to view by getting data from array. and using `foreach `loop just show it back. if you want i can provide sample code of that

Comment: i have passed that $reports array to this view

Comment: will post you sample code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In model**

```
public function get_product()
    {
        $sql = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM tbale_name ");
        $result = $sql->result_array();
        return $result;
    }
```

**In Controller**

```
$data['table'] = $this->Model_Name->get_product();

$this->load->view('admin/product',$data);//pass data to view
```

**In View**

```
<table data-toggle="table" data-show-refresh="true" data-show-toggle="true" data-show-columns="true" data-search="true"  data-pagination="true" data-sort-name="date" data-sort-order="desc" data-show-export="true">
    <tr>
        <th data-field="reportid" data-sortable="true" class="text-center">Report Id</th>
        <th data-field="patientname" data-sortable="true" class="text-center">Patient Name</th>
        <th data-field="date" data-sortable="true" class="text-center">Reg date</th>
        <th data-field="***" data-sortable="true" class="text-center">Test code</th>//set your data in (***)
        <th data-field="***" data-sortable="true" class="text-center">Actions</th>//set your data in (***)
    </tr>
    <?php
        foreach ( $table as $new_table )
        {
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $new_table['id']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $new_table['name']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $new_table['date']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $new_table['code']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $new_table['action']?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php
        }
    ?>
</table>
```

Comment: this is correct but i was looking a way without using those foreach loops

Comment: you can use it bus not sure about passing attributes

Comment: check this https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/issues/1374 and this http://stackoverflow.com/a/15863235/4595675

Comment: @mahethekiller happy to help